# What is the bestway to return a char pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

What is the best way to return or pass strings as in char pointers in c?

I have a function that looks some what like this:

```
char *test_getcwd(){
    char *cwd;
    char *ret;
    if ((cwd = getcwd( ret, pathconf(".",_PC_PATH_MAX) )) == NULL){
        perror ( "Error on calling getcwd() function" );
    }else if (__INCLUDE_LEVEL__ == 0){
        puts( cwd );
    }
    free( cwd );
    return ret;
}
```

Should I change it to:

```
int test_getcwd(const **pass){
    char *cwd;
    char *ret;
    if ((cwd = getcwd( ret, pathconf(".",_PC_PATH_MAX) )) == NULL){
        perror ( "Error on calling getcwd() function" );
    }else if (__INCLUDE_LEVEL__ == 0){
        puts( cwd );
    }
    free( cwd );
        *pass = ret;
    return 0;
}
```

Or leave it as it is or maybe change to something else?

Similar questions may have been asked but my goal is to find the best practice to do it.

Comment: You can't name a variable "return"

Comment: "What is the bestway to" - **There's no "best way".** Decide what you want and design a solution that fits the requirement.

Comment: This code does not work because `getcwd` must be passed either NULL or a pointer to an existing buffer.

Comment: And dont `free(cwd)` if you intend to use the result of the function..

Comment: code #2 has one mistake: **`return`** is a **keyword** and therefore not allowed as an identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `getcwd` must be either NULL or a pointer to an existing buffer. This is also a clue about how to design your routine. Either:

- accept a pointer to an existing buffer as a parameter, and accept a size, and pass those to `getcwd` or
- pass NULL to `getcwd`.

In either case, return a pointer the same way `getcwd` does. Requiring the caller to pass a pointer to something that you set is unnecessarily complicated. So do not do it, just on the principle of keeping things simple.

In the first case, the only reason to return a pointer is to indicate whether an error occurred. When an error does not occur, the caller already knows where the buffer is, since they passed it to the routine.

Your code shows some confusion about the uses of `ret` and `cwd`. If the value passed to `getcwd` in `ret` is not null, then it is the same value returned and assigned to `cwd`. You cannot both free that pointer and return it to the caller to be used. Consider this:

```
char *test_getcwd()
{
    char *ret = getcwd(NULL, ps_test_pathconf(".",_PC_PATH_MAX));
    if (ret == NULL)
        perror("Klaida iškvietus getcwd() funkciją");
    else if (__INCLUDE_LEVEL__ == 0)
        puts(ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: And what about trash handling in you given example do I don't I have to free the ret pointer?

Comment: @PovilasID: The allocated memory should be freed at some time, but it does not have to be in the routine that allocated it. The `test_getcwd` can pass responsibility for that with the pointer it passes: When the caller receives the pointer, they are responsible for ensuring that the memory is freed. (And, when you are developing software to be used by others, this should be part of the documentation of the routine. The documentation will say that the routine returns a pointer that the caller is responsible for freeing.)

Comment: getcwd(3p) says `On some implementations, if buf is a null pointer, getcwd() may obtain size  bytes  of  memory using malloc().  In this case, the pointer returned by getcwd() may be used as the argument in a subsequent call to free().  Invoking getcwd() with buf as a null pointer is not  recommended in conforming applications.`

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but ...

There are three basic ways to return a pointer to a string (or more generally an array) from a function, all of which can be annoyingly inconvenient.

- You can return a pointer to the first element of a `static` array defined inside the function. The size of the array has to be a compile-time constant, and you'll reuse the same array for each call, so successive calls will clobber the results of previous calls.
- You can require the caller to pass in a pointer to the first element an array, possibly with another argument to specify its size. This places a burden on the caller, which has to manage allocation and deallocation and may not have a good way to know the required size.
- You can use `malloc` to allocate the array on the heap. This is the most flexible approach, but it makes the caller responsible for `free`ing the array.

You *can't* just define an array inside the function and return a pointer to its first element. The array ceases to exist when the function returns, leaving you with a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The general C style is that you should return a pointer and return NULL on failure

you need to make it very clear to the caller the ownership of the memory. DO they have or free it or not (and perhaps its thread safety if its static data)

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a char pointer *like that* unless you put it on the heap, or it is inside the same scope as you're using it from (which means you would not be returning it).

What you should do is allocate space on the heap to put your string, then return the address of the pointer from the function.  Then your string is in the heap, and you can access it later.

Comment: Not entirely true. You could put the array into the static .data section, in which case it's not on the stack or the heap.

Comment: Or it is a pointer to a char within a string passed by the caller or otherwise obtained from somewhere outside the function. E.g., `strchr` returns a pointer without having a clue whether it came from dynamic, static, or automatic allocation.

Comment: @Magn3s1um The fact that he's not referring to that doesn't change the fact that your answer is technically incorrect.

Comment: It is still bad advice. `getcwd` already allocates space if needed. Why duplicate function?

Comment: Then he shouldn't free it, and now, getcwd just puts it in his buffer, which is still local scope which means he needs to put it on the heap.